# combobox in mozilla and chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mozilla

This is the code for my select box:

```
<select id="username" name="username" class="form-select ajax-processed" onchange="f1(this.value)">
<option value="">Select User</option>
</select>
```

And style used for this is:

```
input.form-text,textarea.form-textarea,select.form-select { 
border: 1px solid #ccc;
width: 180px;
font-size: 12px;
outline: none;
outline-color: #ccc;
}
```

How to make chrome combo box look same as Mozilla?
when writing `-webkit-appearance`

Comment: What @VijaySarin said. Both these browsers use different rendering engine; AFAIK.

Comment: for this i have worked on a custom combo box. but that was too tedious job.

Comment: What is your main problem here? Size, color, font style?

Comment: My problem is the border style of the combobox. In mozilla the border style is right. but in chrome it is not. When used -webkit-aapearance: none at that time it is same as mozilla but the dropdown list disappears

Comment: do you mean the drop down list or the plain view before clicking it?

Comment: The plain view before clicking it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work for the google chrome. Tried to search a lot but no result. Thank you all for your help...

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is the border style of the combobox.

Then set the border yourself, mate! :)

```
border: 2px solid black;
```

As you can see, it's the same in both browsers:
http://jsfiddle.net/aZt5j/2/